# How to adb shell on Amlogic S905x

Tags: 16.04, usb, android, udev

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

I'm trying to do a adb shell on a leelbox S1 Android 6.0.1 marshmallow which is containing  a chip Amlogic S905x combining a 64bit quad core Cortex A-53.

```
X555UF:~$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision debian
```

When the android box is starting I can see the vendor and product number as :

```
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 1b8e:c003 Amlogic, Inc.
```

but it's gone after 3 minutes and I can not try any connection like I got :

```
adb shell
error: device '(null)' not found
```

However, I set the new udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

```
.../..
#LeelBox
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1b8e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
.../...
```

Also I restarted the udev daemon and no issues.

Comment: Hi @dubis, did you get anywhere ahead with this ? I'm also stuck here with an android box connected over usb but not being recognised. Only showing up as a Composite Device with Amlog vendor using 2 mA current